# Joining tables and sum by attribute

Tags: sql, join, sum

I need to know how many employees does each company have for each country they are present in? I have to join two tables (companies and cities) and sum number of employees for each country.

```
SELECT *, SUM(EMPLOYEES)
    FROM COMPANIES WHERE 
    JOIN CITIES
    ON COMPANIES.CITYNAME = CITIES.CITYNAME
```

doesn´t work...

[Tables to join and sum employees for each country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DoE9.png)

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY` (and other syntax fixes).

Comment: "doesn´t work" is not helpful. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Your problem is a syntax error. You should first have shown as much as possible that the constituent subexpressions were OK. Make it clear that your question is about *that error* & ask re your overall goal later in a new post.

Comment: But re your goal-- (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of tips,

1. Try to alias your joins so your not typing the full table names in your join statements
2. Add a group by on every field your not aggregating on for your sum to work

   ```
       SELECT  CI.COUNTRYNAME,CO.CITYNAME,CO.COMPANYNAME,CI.POPULATION,CI.COUNTRYNAME,
       SUM(EMPLOYEES) AS TOTAL_EMPLOYEES
       FROM COMPANIES AS CO
       JOIN CITIES AS CI
       ON CO.CITYNAME = CI.CITYNAME
       GROUP BY CI.COUNTRYNAME,CO.COMPANYNAME,CO.CITYNAME,CI.POPULATION
   ```

https://rextester.com/DLZNT87647